# Change legend from gradient to specific data values

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I am very new to R, so excuse my question's idiotic nature.  So, currently my data is plotting as such:

[image: operators]

which is fine and dandy, except that the operator values are 1071361 & 1116576.   The client wants the legend to specify only the specific operator values and not the gradient between the values.   The operator values can be different from dataset to dataset in value and number, so I cannot hard code them.   Currently, I have the points as such:

```
g = ggplot(DAT, aes(x=Date, y=Value))
g = g + geom_point(aes(colour=Operator)) + guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = unique(DAT$Operator))))
```

But this is not getting me to my desired result.   Any ideas about how to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use Operator as a categorical variable (so use `factor`)?  Or maybe you need to set the breaks of the color bar in `scale_color_continuous` in some sort of programmatic way?

Comment: @aosmith So, I'm just trying to change the legend to use the specific values contained by Operator.   In the above example, in the data set, Operator is either 1071361 or 1116576 - hence the blue and black colors.  However, the legend on the side contains a gradient of colors between the blue and black and the legend values do not pertain to any of the actual data.

Comment: Ah.  Operator is currently a continuous variable, so you need to specify it is a categorical variable if you want R to treat it as such.  Change it to a factor in the dataset or use `colour = factor(Operator)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following achieve your goal?

```
DAT$Operator <- as.factor(as.character(DAT$Operator))

g = ggplot(DAT, aes(x=Date, y=Value))
g = g + geom_point(aes(colour=Operator))
```

Comment: You don't need both `as.factor` and `as.character`.

Comment: This works as well, but @aosmith is correct, `as.character` was not needed.  But thanks for your help.